# d3.json() function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I have a question for my application logic in d3.js. I send an ajax request(some json data) from client to server and in the server(nodejs) I save into a file. Then I try to fetch json data via the following command.

```
        d3.json("nodes.json", function(error, json) {
        if(error)
        {
            console.warn('nodes.json error', error);
            //throw error;
        }
        console.log("d3.json");
        savedNodesLinks = json;
    });
    console.log('parsed', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedNodesLinks || null)));
    if(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedNodesLinks || null)) != null)
    {
        links = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedNodesLinks || null)).links;
        nodes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedNodesLinks || null)).nodes;
    }
```

This function which consists above-mentioned code snippet is called by a button. When I click the button first time, 'savedNodesLinks' variable shows as an undefined. When I push the button second time, data comes in a robust way. How can I fix this issue? I debugged the code but I couldn't find the problem

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The d3.json() call is asynchronous, meaning it doesn't get the json right away. When the json is available the function where you have your `console.log("d3.json")` is called. At that point it is available. Meantime your `console.log()` call after d3.json() is called (before your json is available), so savedNodesLinks is not yet defined. I would suggest reading up on asynchronous calls in javascript to better understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

savedNodeLinks is used outside the scope try using your code inmediatelly after `saveNodesLinks = json`.

Because `console.log('parsed', ...` will occur before actually server returns the nodes.json file

```
    d3.json("nodes.json", function(error, json) {
    if(error)
    {
        console.warn('nodes.json error', error);
        //throw error;
    }
    console.log("d3.json");
    savedNodesLinks = json;
    console.log('parsed', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedNodesLinks || null)));
    if(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedNodesLinks || null)) != null)
    {
        links = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedNodesLinks || null)).links;
        nodes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(savedNodesLinks || null)).nodes;
    }
});
```

It's not about d3.js, it's about javascript asynchronous programming.
Check [Introduction to asynchronous JavaScript](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean try using your code immediately after saveNodesLinks=json?